# Sonar.properties for Multi module project showing less Code coverage

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am using below Sonar properties for a multi module java project. I got code coverage of 9.4%. But when I saw results in sonarqube ,only few no# of test results were capturing. Am I missing anything here.

```
sonar.projectKey=Sample
sonar.projectName=sample
sonar.projectVersion=$PipelineId
sonar.modules=admin,client-api,common,om,serviceproviders
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
sonar.sources=.
sonar.skipPackageDesign=true
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

[image]

Comment: try adding `sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8` and `sonar.skipPackageDesign=true`

Comment: @AvinashRavilla No Luck its still displaying 9.4% of CV

Comment: how do you do the analysis, with which scanner (gradle, maven, jenkins, ..)? can you post the logout put of the scanner? it is quite hard to put wild guesses here, if you use gradle just add -i for more information :D

Comment: @ltsimmens I am executing this in Jenkins.Attached screen shot.

Comment: i would also recommend to put the log output into your task description from the sonar scanner, if there is not enough output, maybe, there is somekind of flag which you can activate, but still it is hard to guess what is wrong based on that amount of information

Comment: the question is also, is cobertura only providing one test file, or do you have more coverage files? what is the jenkins configuration regarding computing of coverage? maybe you are missing some coverage files?

Comment: @ltsimmens How should I include Integration tests in sonar properties file. I found that I missed including them. I am using Cobertura tool here to publish in sonar.

Comment: well imho i would not use cobertura, i would use jacoco ... cobertura is also deprecated, and is not supported with newer versions... take a look at https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project for usage etc